# Org-refile locks up file when used from org capture

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I like to use org-refile to refile notes during the capture process. But,  since org-refile does not saves the file after the refiling is done, the file ends up being locked up and I need to visit the file and manually save the buffer in order to access it from another emacs process or another application. Emacs also ask me if I want to save the file upon exit.

Is there anyway to make org-refile save the file automatically after the capture process is done?

I also note that after refiling there is no buffer opened associated with the file, still, if I visit the file the buffer appears as modified and the changes are not saved.

Comment: there's no "after-refile hook" (I think), but you can just add an advice `:after` to `org-refile` to save the current buffer if it's associated with a file.  See [Advising Emacs Lisp Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

Comment: Which version of emacs are you using, and which version of `org-mode`? You can find your `org-mode` version with `M-x org-version`. For me, using `org-refile` from the `org-capture` buffer works fine, and the first thing I see in the echo area is `Wrote /path/to/my/org/file` indicating that the file was indeed saved after capture. My suspicion is that whatever file you are refiling to is open in another emacs frame/instance. Could this be the case?

Comment: @ramus `org-after-refile-insert-hook` runs after the entry is put in the new location, but before it is removed from the old.

Comment: @elethan, I'm using org 8.3.2, I get the same message in the echo area but the file is still not saved.

Comment: I have added an advice to org-refile to save all org buffers following @rasmus comment. This fixes the problem, how do I mark this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

There is no hook for `org-refile` that could usefully save the buffer (there's `org-after-refile-insert-hook` but it won't help).  Since you're capturing you can use `org-capture-after-finalize-hook` to save.  Since you're refiling you don't know which file needs to be save, so just save them all:

```
(add-hook 'org-capture-after-finalize-hook #'org-save-all-org-buffers)
```

Comment: Adding this hook does not work, I think the refiled buffer closes before capture finalizes. But adding an advice to org-refile to save all buffers after refiling seems to work. See rasmus comment to the main post.

Comment: `org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook` claims the capture buffer is still  current when it runs.  Perhaps that would work?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used:

```
(defun save-after-capture-refile ()
  (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer org-capture-last-stored-marker)
    (save-buffer)))
(advice-add 'org-capture-refile :after 'save-after-capture-refile)
```